# How to setup Basic authentication in RestKit with Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, restkit-0.20

I'm using RestKit to make access to my REST API. As showed in their tutorial i decided to use Code Data for storing results from my REST API. Everything is ok but i have a trouble to setup a Basic Authentication with the RestKit. 
So i have this code:

```
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];

RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"Id":       @"id",
     @"Category": @"category",
     @"Name":     @"name",
     @"Price":    @"price"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/products/" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://win8virtual:49876/api/products/"]];    


RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *managedObjectRequestOperation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];

managedObjectRequestOperation.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:managedObjectRequestOperation];
```

I can't find the place where to add login and password information.
In some answers on this site i found information about RKObjectManager:
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"1" password:@"1"];

But how to use it in my case?

**Edit:** I found a solution.
Instead of code above use this:

```
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://win8virtual:49876"]];
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
 [objectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"1" password:@"1"];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"Id":       @"id",
     @"Category": @"category",
     @"Name":     @"name",
     @"Price":    @"price"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/products/" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
// Добавляем описание ответа в менеджер объектов, чтобы он автоматом обрабатывал запросы по url
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
// Request!
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/products/" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of code above use this:

```
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://win8virtual:49876"]];
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
 [objectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"1" password:@"1"];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"Id":       @"id",
     @"Category": @"category",
     @"Name":     @"name",
     @"Price":    @"price"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/products/" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
// Добавляем описание ответа в менеджер объектов, чтобы он автоматом обрабатывал запросы по url
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
// Request!
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/products/" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

The main idea is to use RKObjectManager for any requests. It can be automatically generate Request by self contained information.